# Cosine similarity on vectors with unbounded components

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

I have vectors with most components bounded between 0 and 1. There are a few other components that are unbounded and can be very large. When I compute cosine similarity, I want each component to have equal weight in the similarity calculation.

```
a = [0.4,0.6,0.2,11100]
b = [0.2,0.8,0.1,9000]
```

Does anyone know how to best solve this problem?

This is important because when calculating the similarity between a and b, the result is dominated by the fourth component of the two vectors, which makes the calculation pretty fruitless.

If you want some context, the features between 0 and 1 are things like danceability, instrumentalness. But I would like squash song duration (miliseconds) and beats per minute to be between 0 and 1 while respecting the dsitributions that these two random variables take on. I think the distribution is important because a 10 minute song (unusual) should matter a lot more than a 3 minute song (common).

I thought of dividing all those high number features by their max in the dataset, but then you assume your dataset is representative of all the music in the world.

I thought of doing a kernel density estimation and then calculating their cdf output (bounded between 0 and 1).

I could plug them into the sigmoid function, but this ignores the distribution.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: yep. it's underneath the code block

Comment: It seems like you need a mapping function.  `ln(minutes)` would map 3 minutes to 1, 10 minutes to 2.3.

Comment: Yes, ideally the mapping will preserve the distribution of the data so that we more accurately can project song length as a distance in that coordinate direction.